# Calculating the bounding points for the area of a "Pie Segment" and "sub areas"

Tags: c#, math, gdi+, pie-chart

**Background**:

I was recently playing around with GDI+ to draw a "Disc" displaying a sweeping color change through 360 degrees. (I dug up some HSL to RGB code to loop through HSL(1,1,1) -> HSL(360,1,1))

Regarding the disc, I first drew a full solid circle using the above, and then a second circle in Grey over the center to give the following

[image]

So this is all fine... but I realised that GDI+ is insulating us from a lot of the tricky match that's going on here by way of the `FillPie` method. Also, `FillPie` requires you to supply a bounding rectangle for the pie as opposed to a Radius Length. It also does a full segment fill and doesnt allow you to specify a part of that segment only.

**Question:**

Can anyone point me in the direction of some Math functions or give any explanation on what forumla I would need to calculate the area & plot points of the following "Green Filled Area" given:

```
Point `c` - an x,y co-ordinate
Angle `A` - an angle from horizontal
Angle `B  - an angle from horizontal where `B` - `A` == the sweep angle
Length `r` - a distance from `c`
Length `r2` - a distance from `c` where `r2` - `r` == the `height` of the segment to be filled.
```

[image]

Links to Math sources are fine but I've had a quick google & look at Wolfram Math and could find what I was looking for. Also, if there was some way to generate a sequence of bounding (x,y) co-or's that could be passed as a `Point[]` to Graphics.FillPolygon, that'd be cool too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The area is the difference of the outer and inner disc parts.  The area of a disc part is proportional to the angle sweep:

```
area = (b-a)*((r+r2)^2-r^2)/2
```

`a` and `b` must be expressed in radians.
For `b-a = 2*Pi`, `area = Pi*(r+r2)^2 - Pi*r^2` is the difference of the areas of the outer and inner discs.

You can generate points on the inner / outer circle using

```
x = cx + r * cos(t)     /     x = cx + (r+r2) * cos(t)
y = cy + r * sin(t)     /     y = cy + (r+r2) * sin(t)
```

Where `t` varies from `a` to `b`.

Comment: +1 eric. Thanks. Am I to assume that the smaller the increment on t between A & B, then the better the resolution of your points...

e.g. if A is 30* & B is 45*, then the more increments you place between the A & B, the better the resolution of your Curve...

Low Res = (30, 35, 40, 45)
High Res = (30, 30.5, 31, 31.5, ... 44.5, 45)

Comment: Yes, ideally the increment should correspond to some number of pixels on the outer circle.  The arc length between points on the outer circle is (r+r2)*dt, where dt is the angle increment in radians.

Comment: +1. @Eoin, see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/vect.html for vector construction/operation formulas to see where Eric's formulas some from.

Comment: I think Eoin is using r2 for the outer radius, while you use r2+r.
This might lead to confusion. Otherwise this is nicely explained.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. The second part provides a method for calculating the area of a sector of a circle

http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-the-Area-of-a-Circle

Comment: Cheers, it's not so much the actual area in units^2 I'm looking for but the points that define that area on the plane... I've updated the question subject to reflect this. Cheers though, good resource.

Comment: Are we to assume that we know point c, the angles A and B and the radii r1 and r2 and you *want* the intercept points? e.g. the point produced by adding the vector produced by A and r1 to c (to get one inner point, then Ar1+Ar2+c to get the outer point on the same path... then ditto for B side?

Comment: @Jonathan. Yep. Assume c, A, B, r & r2 are known inputs to some formula which will spit out a Point[] array which could be used to draw a line, bouding that area.

Answer (score 0):

The area of a segment of a circle is simply the angle of the arc (in radians) times the radius. So the area of the green circle is obviously:

```
(B-A) * r2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to draw lines (this pseudo code):

```
for aa from A to B
  set color to required color // you could use aa in an equation with HSL to get something like your sample
  x1=r*cos(aa)+x
  y1=r*sin(aa)+y
  x2=r1*cos(aa)+x
  y2=r1*sin(aa)+y
  draw line between (x1,y1) and (x2,y2)
```

for a small-enough increment in the angles, and small-enough radii, this should be OK.

The points you're looking for are (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) for each angle aa